# How should I name the tables and models for 'user category' and 'article category'?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, naming-conventions

How should I name the tables and models for user category and article category? I have two tables one users and the other articles. I want to categorize these so that I can for example just call the news articles or use just users that are in the company category. So I need relationships between these models/tables.

I thought about to use a single table and a single model for both article and user but these two don't have much in common plus that could be a problem when I'll bind the relationships between them.

Laravel uses the singular style naming for pivot table, I don't want to break that. So I can't use singular names for these as well. My current choice is:

```
Article --> main model 
articles --> main table
ArticleCategory --> relational model
articles_categories --> relational table
--------------------------------------
User --> main model
users --> main table
UserCategory --> relational model
users_categories --> relational table
```

So what do you think? Should I use this way or is there a better way to go?

Comment: Your naming looks fine. You can go on with this approach. I guess articles_tables should be renamed in articles_categories

Comment: I fixed and edited it thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Eloquent Model you can set table name for your particular model.Simple example for User model is as below:-

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'articles';

}
```

check this [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) you can easily understand. Thanks

Comment: Yes i know that they can be customized but I don't want to break the general convention of laravel.

Comment: okk....you can use the singular style naming for pivot table in laravel and  Laravel conventions are a bit different but you can override them in the model classes. Within each model class and each relation method you can specify the table name and the fields you'd like to use when considering a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

best way is:php artisan make:model User -m
with this way laravel create model and migration name and file automatically